# Shutil.move() not working with Task Scheduler despite working manually

Tags: python, automation, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on using Task Scheduler to run this program every morning. The python program works fine when I run it manually, but throws a FileNotFoundError when done with Task Scheduler. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
original = "C:/Users/work/thing/thing.xlsx"
target = "C:/Users/{}/place of work/work Team - 
Documents/General/thing".format(user)

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(target, "thing.xlsx")):
    os.remove(os.path.join(target, "thing.xlsx"))

shutil.move(original, target)

print("Program executed without errors.")
```

Comment: Which user account do you have Task Scheduler configured to run this under? Which user account do you run it with when you test by hand?

Comment: BTW, I'd be very (extremely) surprised if this was specific to `shutil.move` and didn't also happen with `os.rename`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need the `os.remove()` -- and, if you don't need it, you shouldn't have it. Renaming a file to a destination that overwrites an existing file is the standard way to do an atomic update of that file ("atomic" meaning that it either succeeds and you get the new file, or it fails and you still have the old file). When you add an explicit remove you lose that atomicity, because you can have a case where the remove succeeds but the rename fails, so you end up with no file at the destination at all.

Comment: Anyhow -- if it _isn't_ a file permissions issue, then the most likely fallback is that `user` has a value that isn't what you expect it to be. (For example, if you're reading the username from a file, maybe you're forgetting to strip the newline on the end).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the administrative user, and it only occurs with os.rename

Comment: "Only occurs with os.rename"? Wasn't this question _asked_ because it was observed with `shutil.move`?

Comment: Also, the user value has a correct value. I'll muck around with os.remove as you suggested. Thank you for the help.

Comment: *shutil.move(), sorry mate

Comment: Are any of these home directories on a network store? If a Kerberos token (or whatever Microsoft calls them in Active Directory parlance) is needed for access, that would explain a daemon running as Administrator not having the access. Would also explain `os.rename` and `shutil.move` behaving differently, because at least on POSIXy systems (Windows is outside my area of expertise) they should be identical when both source and destination names are on the same filesystem.

Comment: BTW, the suggestion to remove the `remove` was focused on not losing atomicity (to improve your failure modes), not on fixing the immediate bug.

Comment: The file is created locally and, using `shutil.move()`, the file is moved into a network drive. I think I understand... is there a way to surpass the need for a Kerberos token required for access OR a way to give the daemon access?

Comment: Assuming it really is a Kerberos token issue -- yes, you can save tokens on the filesystem and give services access to them. However, when I last did that it was with either MIT Kerberos or Heimdal Kerberos for UNIX (and over a decade ago), so I have no idea what the equivalent procedure is in the version Microsoft built for AD.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I fixed the issue. I made the script an executable file then used Task Scheduler, with the highest permissions granted and hidden, and it works fine now. Not sure why... but I'll take it! Thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by converting the python script into an executable file (via pyinstaller) and then making the exe program the action from Task Scheduler. Some ticked properties include -"grant highest permissions" I also removed the need for `shutil.move()` by just creating and writing to a file in the cloud location.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to move the file to a network directory.
Problem lied on Task Scheduler
On the Task's general settings, make sure to check the option
[Run whether user is logged in or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utrK1.png)
and uncheck the Not Save Password option.
You will be prompted with a password request.